# Transform PHP string

Tags: php, html, css, angular, wordpress

This is the response payload from the REST interface: `".my-test-class {\n\tbackground-color: blue;\n\tcolor: white;\n}"`

I would like this to be:

```
.my-test-class {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Without the double quotes and without the escape characters.. [something like this](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/css/css/space.css).. just plain CSS.. and **I would like to transform this on the server-side**.

The method behind the `GET` does this:

```php
public function get_custom_css()
{
  $custom_css = wp_get_custom_css();

  $response = new WP_HTTP_Response($custom_css, 200, [
    "Content-Type" => "text/css; charset=UTF-8"
  ]);

  return rest_ensure_response($response);
}
```

Doing a `$custom_css = trim($custom_css, '"');` to get rid of the double quotes did not work as the first  character is the dot (`$custom_css[0] == '.'`). The double quotes seem to be applied later.

I receive the response via Angular like this:

```js
this.httpClient.get('http://my.domain.com/wordpress/?rest_route=/custom/css', {
  responseType: 'text'
})
  .subscribe((css: string): void => {
    const styleElement: HTMLStyleElement = document.createElement<'style'>('style');

    const textNode: Text = document.createTextNode(css);
    styleElement.appendChild(textNode);

    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
  });
```

And the result is this:

```html
<style>".my-test-class {\n\tbackground-color: blue;\n\tcolor: white;\n}"</style>
```

Which of course is not valid CSS and therefore not applied correctly.

#### Update (2020-12-22)

As suggested in @imvain2s answer, I decided to omit new line and tab characters. I see no reason in keeping them in the final CSS. So I am now using this to remove the escape sequences:

```php
$custom_css = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t]+/', '', $custom_css);
```

As it is done in line 5403 in the `_sanitize_text_fields` function ([link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_sanitize_text_fields/))

The result is now:

```html
<style>".my-test-class {background-color: blue;color: white;}"</style>
```

It still has these double quotes and my guess is that WordPress adds them when the response is send back.

I found other articles and questions speaking about "magic quotes" (see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+magic+quotes)), but I am not yet sure if these are related.

Comment: I did some research on the web and inside the WordPress code and this all looks like this was made for JSON. Single strings are wrapped with double quotes as if they were a JSON string value. So as of now, I am just wrapping the custom CSS in a JSON object (with one property ..  .. so redundant). But if someone finds an answer to this, please let me know. Here is [a related question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/return-plain-text-from-register_rest_route/) from another forum about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the function correctly, you should be able to apply the CSS on the response.

Also, since new lines and tabs aren't needed in actual CSS, I just removed the string versions of them.

```
    public function get_custom_css()
    {
      $custom_css = wp_get_custom_css();
    
      $response = new WP_HTTP_Response($custom_css, 200, [
        "Content-Type" => "text/css; charset=UTF-8"
      ]);
      
    $response = rest_ensure_response($response);
    
    $response = trim($response, '"');
    $response = str_replace("\\n","",$response);
    $response = str_replace("\\t","",$response);

/*
  or to keep the new lines and tabs
    $response = str_replace("\\n","\n",$response);
    $response = str_replace("\\t","\t",$response);
*/
    
      return $response;
    }
```

Comment: It does not work like that, because the result from `rest_ensure_response` ([link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_ensure_response/)) is a `WP_REST_Response` ([link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/)) object. So I tried this with just the data instead and did `$tmp = $response->get_data();`. Did `trim` and `str_replace` on that value and wrote it back with `$response->set_data($tmp);` but that also did not work, the result is unchanged. I even tried `'\n'` and `'\t'` in the `str_replace` .. 

Comment: I think, just stripping the new lines and tabs is a good idea. It works now with `str_replace` when using just one backslash, so this removes the new line: `str_replace("\n", '', $custom_css)` and `preg_replace('/[\r\n\t]+/', '', $custom_css)` also works and remove these escape sequences from the string.